# How to programmatically add Tooltip for InlineEditBox in dojo 1.8

Tags: dojo, tooltip, inlineeditbox

I'm using dojo 1.8.1 and have two inline editors, one for a Textarea, and one for an Editor. I would like to provide flyover tips to help explain how they should be used. Ideally, I'd like to seed the inline editor's textarea / editor with a hint if there is no content, and have this disappear when they click to edit the missing content (the underlines with the writer icon didn't do it for me -- if I can replace that span that would be okay too). However, as a start it would be nice to have a tooltip show when mousing over the entry area.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter in the constructor for the InlineEditBox called noValueIndicator where you can put the hint for content when none has been supplied and it disappears when the editor has focus for entry.  Too simple -- horses, not zebras...